# Limitar input type color solo a blanco y negro

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un script en el que se puede cambiar de color con un `input type="color"`

Lo que quiero es que en el `input` en vez de elegir todo el abanico de colores que da, que solo pueda elegir entre blanco o negro.

Es eso posible?? 
O lo tendre que hacer con dos `radio buttons`??

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Elegircolor</label>
             <input type="color" id="colorElegido" value="#000000" name="product_color" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas, puedes añadir el contenido del script?

Comment: ten en cuenta que type="color"  no funciona en IE o Edge

Comment: Ya he añadido el html @sakulino

Comment: La web entera no funciona en IE, asi que no es problema jeje @lois6b

Comment: @lois6b `type='color'` si funciona en Edge.

Comment: @rnd oh, mis disculpas, a partir del 14 si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que es una opción binaria (blanco/negro), una  alternativa seria utilizar un solo checkbox y un poco de css para mostrar bien lo que quieres, es decir dos colores como opcion.

Luego solo usas el valor del checkbox para saber que color ha elejido el usuario: checked = negro, unchecked = blanco

Salu2.

```css
.select-color  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}

.select-color input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.select-color button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.select-color input[type=checkbox]:checked + button {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
Color: 
<div class="select-color">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <button></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar este codigo que vendria siendo un radiobutton pero en la apariencia de color picker:

Aunque sale la opcion "otros"...

Puedes poner un evento onChange en el input y si es distinto al Blanco y Negro que lo notifique al usuario.

```html
   <input type="color" id="some id" name="someName" list="rainbow" value="#000000">
<datalist id="rainbow">
    <option value="#000000">Negro</option>
    <option value="#FFFFFF">Blanco</option>

</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente, me gusta la [solución de lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26806/250) (sin necesidad de utilizar JavaScript), pero tiene el problema de que no funciona del todo en Firefox e IE/Edge, y además permite elegir colores no válidos (incluso en Chrome pulsando en el botón de "Otros..."). Así que voy a poner una alternativa con JavaScript, quizás si combinas esta solución con la de lois6b, podrías obtener algo interesante.

La idea sería añadir un controlador para el evento `onchange` que, cada vez que el campo cambie de valor, compruebe si el nuevo valor es parte de una lista de colores válidos; y si no lo es, haga que el valor del campo vuelva a ser uno por defecto.

Algo como esto:

```js
// añadir un controlador del evento onChange
document.getElementById("colorElegido").addEventListener("change", function(e) {

  // lista de colores válidos
  var coloresValidos = ["#ffffff", "#000000"];

  // si el nuevo valor no es válido, entonces poner el valor por defecto
  if (coloresValidos.indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
    e.target.value = "#000000";
  }

}, false);
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Elegircolor</label>
    <input type="color" id="colorElegido" value="#000000" name="product_color" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: y añadiria un alert. puede no ser muy elegante pero si soy un usuario que selecciona verde y que sigue seleccionado negro no me dice que solo pueda elegir dos colores, me dice que la aplicacion no funciona